# LibreOffice Upgrade from 3.5.4 to 4.3.3 Broke Lots of Macros

Tags: libreoffice, macro

Recently upgraded from **Debian Wheezy** to **Jessie** (yeah, I know...). During said upgrade, the **LibreOffice** suite got upgraded from version **3.5.4** to **4.3.3**.

Well, lots of my Writer macros were broken after said upgrade.

Is anyone aware of any issues that could have caused this as a result of said upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, at some time after version **3.5.4**, LibreOffice changed the protocol by which they title various styles (FYI, in the example shown below, it is a *paragraph* style that is referenced).

A snippet of code from a Writer macro which was broken by the subject upgrade (FYI, I use the **Record** method to create most of my macros):

```
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args13(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args13(0).Name = "Template"
args13(0).Value = "First line indent"
args13(1).Name = "Family"
args13(1).Value = 2

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:StyleApply", "", 0, args13())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the format of the named style, "First line indent". I discovered that, if I merely capitalized said style name (replacing `First line indent` with `First Line Indent`), this fixed my macro:

```
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args13(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args13(0).Name = "Template"
args13(0).Value = "First Line Indent"
args13(1).Name = "Family"
args13(1).Value = 2

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:StyleApply", "", 0, args13())

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And, like substitutions for other so broken macros fixed them, too!

End of problem.